# After upgrading to Numpy 1.8.2, ImportError: cannot import name multiarray

Tags: python, numpy, upgrade, importerror, anaconda

I just upgraded to Numpy 1.8.2 on my 64-bit Windows machine using Anaconda's Spyder. I used the command:

`conda update numpy`

It installed it. Before that I had numpy 1.7.1, and I also have a 32-bit version of anaconda spyder in another path, but I 've taken it out of the system PATH variable.

Now the issue is that as soon as I try to run any code, I get an error that ends in:

```
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
```

One of the first imports in `___init___.py` for numpy is:

```
from . import multiarray
```

But in `C:\Users\app\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core` I can see the following two files:

```
multiarray.pyd
multiarray_tests.pyd
```

What should I do to get this working? Is re-installing really the only way to get it working?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `conda info -a`?

Comment: did you solve this? I am facing same issue and desperately looking for an answer

Comment: This solution worked for me. http://askubuntu.com/a/569551/573611 I don't know why.